# Flash Game 'falling' movieclips

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, movieclip

I'm gonna make a small Flash game where movieclips go downwards. Very easy to make of course but I want to make a static level. I want to draw this level in Adobe Flash CS4 (drag movieclips in a big movieclip for example). So in the game I'm planning to lower this big movieclip couple of pixels per frame. But this movieclip needs to have a length of like 50.000 pixels of course. So I wonder, how would you guys make this feature of the game.

Comment: Do you mean you have a platformer style game where the entire level (so combination of many MovieClips) keeps moving down?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work, smooth performance.
I make a big rectangle (900x5000). I cut the middle background out of it (for performance and it forces the rectangle to stay 5000px big (5000px is maximum length of a shape in CS4)). I make it a movieclip. Then I put small movieclips in it (falling items) and make it a MC of that aswell. I place that on the stage and make it go up 3px per frame. I got a check and a function to make sure it will paste the next big MC after the current MC when it has reach it ends.